# Need Advice on the Cost of Replacement Windows and Stucco Repair After Being Swindled by a Window Salesman!

Tags: repair, windows, stucco, contractors

So, I live in the desert southwest where it's been pushing 100 in summer and snows much of the winter. I've been renovating my own home for the past few years and have gotten to a point where I just want to hire some of the larger projects out. In particular I have 3 large windows that need replacing (old, aluminum, single pane, and drafty) and I'd like to re stucco my house, though that is not totally necessary right now. I have competently replaced windows but I just don't want to do it again, and the stucco has cracks / crappy repair work and is a giant job I don't want to do solo. So, when a door-to-door salesman came by the other day offering both these services I did sign up for a consult.

Long story short the guy talked my ear off, was convincing and got me to sign up for 3 mid range Provia brand windows installed for $6,300. What really sold me was the heat and cold insulation and that heat lamp demo they do. After he left I started googling pricing on windows and I feel like a total sucker. I am now negotiating the price with him, and have a few days to back out if I want. In this process they have offered me a restucco (with custom color) on my house + the windows for $12K including tax. They are dropping the windows to $5,500 - which still feels like a lot. Altogether though, this price seems fair when I look into the cost of stucco. I need to measure, but I'm guessing my home is around 1,500 feet - it's a small 3bdr with a garage.

Please give me thoughts / advice (aside from doing it myself) on the cost of the windows, the stucco or both.

Thanks!

Comment: Get more quotes.  It is your money and one sweet talking guy is not the only fish in the pond.  Half to three quarters of what they say is hot air/stuff that comes from the backend of a cow/bull.  There are sun films you placed on windows for about 10/20 dollars that work as well with a heat lamp.

Answer (score 1):

It seems steep to me; the best way to know if the price is good is to get a comparable bid from someone else for the same work.

The biggest red flag I see is that the thing we're talking about was sold to you by a door-to-door salesman. Some have good products, and some are honest, but imagine how much they must be making on each sale to make it worth their time to offset all the rejections they must get.